# Elementary question on lower semicontinuity: Definition

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Below is the definition of a lower semicontinuous function:

> We say that $\; f\;$ is lower semi-continuous at $\; x_{0} \;$ if for
>   every $\; \epsilon \gt 0\;$ there exists a neighborhood $\; \mathcal U
>  \;$ of $\;x_{0} \;$ such that $\; f(x)\ge f(x_{0})-\epsilon \;$ for
>   all $ \; x \in \mathcal U\;$  when $\;f(x_{0})<+\infty  \;$ , and
>   $\;f(x)\;$ tends to $\; +\infty \;$ as $\;x\;$ tends towards $\;
>  x_{0}\;$ when $\; f(x_{0})=+\infty\; $ . Equivalently, in the case of
>   a metric space, this can be expressed as:
>
> $\; \liminf _{x\to x_{0}}f(x)\ge f(x_{0})\;$ .

**I'd like to know why the equivalence in the definition holds.** I thought that will be a connection between the $\; \epsilon$-definition of infimum of a bounded set and the definition above but I'm missing the details.

I would appreciate if somebody could help me through this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of metric space $(X,d)$ "there exists a neighborhood $\mathcal U$" is replaced by "there exists $\delta>0$" and neighborhood $B(x_0,\delta)$ is considered ($x\in B(x_0,\delta) \iff d(x_0,x)<\delta$). First definition (containing neighborhood $\mathcal U$) can be now reformulated as:

1. $f(x_0)<+\infty$
   $$ \forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta >0\ \forall x\in X: d(x_0,x)<\delta \implies f(x)\ge f(x_0)-\epsilon$$
2. $f(x_0)=+\infty$
   $$ \forall M>0\ \exists \delta >0\ \forall x\in X: d(x_0,x)<\delta \implies f(x)\ge M$$

In simple words (1.-st case): for every $\epsilon>0$ all $x$-es thet are sufficiently close to $x_0$ have value $f(x)\ge f(x_0)-\epsilon$. So there is no sequence $x_n\rightarrow x_0$ such that $f(x_n)\rightarrow a<f(x_0)$. Therefore $\liminf_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)\ge f(x_0)$. 2.-nd case is similar.